# How can I make a comparison using paraview's programmable filter?

Tags: python, numpy, paraview

I'm trying to make a simple comparison using Paraview's programmable filter. In summary, this will be necessary because I need to see my problem's solution only in the points that I have values higher than 100.0, for example. It's supposed to be simple, right? What am I missing here?

```
mydata = inputs[0].PointData['T']

print(mydata[0])
if(mydata[0] > 100.0):
    print("True")
else: 
    print("False")
```

I expect this output to be "False" since mydata[0] = 7.282856964183867e-48, but the actual output is "True". My input file [can be downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lauexz8bmr1jd6v/output15.e?dl=0).

Comment: Hello ACR. Could you share a sample of data ?

Comment: Hello Bertrand, I've edited my post to include the input file I'm using. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a multiblock dataset. It can't be accessed like a standard dataset. See the discussion [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17651) :

The correct way to implement your programmable filter with a multiblock dataset input is as follows :

```
mydata = inputs[0].PointData['T']

print(mydata.Arrays[0]|0])
if(mydata.Arrays[0]|0] > 100.0):
    print("True")
else: 
    print("False")
```

The first index being the block index, the second being the values index.

Another solution is to add a **MergeBlocks** filter between your reader and your programmable filter.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the simple workaround. This will do for now. :)

Comment: Thank you one more time for the careful explanation. I got an error trying your solution `NameError: name 'RequestData' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you made a typo somewhere. You should share the full error.